# How to find bit length of text with specific font and font size

Tags: text, size, nativescript

I'm developing NativeScript JavaScript code to create dynamic text marker for maps. I have the code working that creates a marker for a specific string.  My next step is to take any given string, determine its height and width in bits, and create the marker sized to contain the text.

My problem is finding the size of the text, given the text string itself, the font size, and the font family.

It looks like getMeasuredWidth could work, except that the string must already be loaded on a page before that function will return a value.  In my case, I simply need to compute the size; the text won't otherwise appear as such on a page (the text in the marker becomes an image).

Is there a way to do this?

```
var bmp = BitmapFactory.create(200);
bmp.dispose(function (b) {
try {
  b.drawRect(
    "100,34", // size
    '0,0', // upper-left coordinate
    KnownColors.Black, // border color
    KnownColors.Cornsilk // fill color
  );

  b.writeText(
    "Parking",
    "2,25",
    { color: KnownColors.Black, size: 8, name: 'fontawesome-webfont', });

...
```

In the code above, the width of "100" of the bounding rectangle actually represents the bit width of "Parking" with a small amount of padding. What I want to does calculate the rectangle's height and width and not hard-code it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, finding label size without adding it to Page upon button click

```
export function onFindButtonTap(args: EventData) {
 const button = <any>args.object;

 const label = new Label();
 label.text = "Hello, found my size?"
 label.fontSize = 20;

 (<any>label)._setupAsRootView(button._context);
 label.onLoaded();
 label.measure(0, 0);
 console.log(`Width : ${label.getMeasuredWidth()} x Height : ${label.getMeasuredHeight()}`);
}
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=drSOUV)

*Note:* I didn't get a chance to test it with iOS yet, let me know if you hit any issues.

Comment: you always come through with an answer!  This is an interesting approach, and seems to work.  But... I can't find any info on _setupAsRootView().  Can this be any view, and does that view already have to be loaded?

Comment: Here you find about [_setupAsRootView](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_core_view_base_.viewbase#_setupasrootview), it's a private method and you could use it if you understand the View class. And yes, this is applicable for any View, not just label.

Comment: Hmm, that's exactly the page I was looking at, but still didn't find anything by that name.  But, does whichever view is used have ti be loaded?  I'd like to find the text dimensions in onNavigatedTo, if not earlier at viewModel creation time.

Comment: You can perform this task at any time after app is started.

Comment: I've experimented with Manoj's answer and concluded it will work for me.  The trick is getting the right object's _context variable.  I used the MapView object, thusly:

    mapView = page.getViewById("locMap");
    label._setupAsRootView(mapView._context);

Where locMap is defined as:

     <maps:mapView id="locmap" latitude="{{ latitude }}" longitude="{{ longitude }}" zoom="{{ zoom }}" visibility="{{ isBusy ? 'collapsed' : 'visible' }}" mapReady="onMapReady" markerSelect="onMarkerSelect" markerInfoWindowTapped="onMarkerInfoWindowTapped">